# Regex for splitting paragraph into sentences

Tags: python, regex

i have written following regex expression to match sentence end and ignore the special case like U.S,U.S.A, Ser. No. , Pat. No.(it should not split here as sentence not end here) but it is not giving correct output.
here is my regex:-

```
((?:[A-Z]+\sU\.S\.)|(?:\w\.(\s?\w{1,12}\.)+)|(?:[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\.\s+[A-Z]+)|(?:°\s?[cCfF]\.)|(?:\s+[\(]*[a-h0-9]{1}\))|(?:\.\s*Fig.{1,7}\.)|(?:([.?!;])\s*(?=[\`\’A-Za-z\(])))
```

here is the example paragraph:

> This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013. Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004. Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph. Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph.

i tried my regex but it is not giving expected result.

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MyUvIH/1)

Answer (score 1):

My approach is using a 3rd package that supports infinite width for negative lookbehind to ignore all special case

Package [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) could help

```
(?<!U\.S|Ser|No|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Pat|Fig)\.(?= [A-Z\d])
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2cUNFY/1) (note that i use .NET engine here instead of Python because it support infinite lookbehind for demonstration)

**Explanation**:

- `(?<!U\.S|Ser|No|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Pat|Fig)` Negative look behind to ignore all `.` that starts with these special words.
- `\.` match a dot `.`
- `(?= [A-Z\d])`: Positive look ahead to make sure it followed by a space and a Uppercase character or a digit

Install **regex** package

```
pip instal regex
```

Programming:

```
import regex
s = "This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013. Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004. Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph. Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph. 1 new sentences added to this text block."
lines = regex.split(r"(?<!U\.S|Ser|No|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Pat|Fig)\.(?= [A-Z\d])", s)
for line in lines:
  print(line)
```

Output:

```
This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013
 Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004
 Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph
 Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph
 1 new sentences added to this text block.
```

**Note:** If there is no line that starts with a digit like my last added sentences `1 new sentences added to this text block.`, a simplier version should work:

```
(?<!U\.S|Ser|No|Pat|Fig)\.(?= [A-Z])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is there any other method to do that as the above paragraph is only example?. i would require to add a lot of negative lookbehind and also i wouldn't be knowing what word to add more. can it be done using non-capturing group like what i have done by updating something?

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: since in this case, the regular expression might grow to be quite complex, I would opt to use a library.*

**Use the stanza library**

If a regular expression isn't a requirement, one option is to use [stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/):

```
import stanza

stanza.download('en')
# define pipeline
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang="en", processors='tokenize')
# create document
doc = nlp(text)
# extract sentences
doc_sentences = [sentence.text for sentence in doc.sentences]

for s in doc_sentences:
    print(s)
```

This gives the following result and works well even with abbreviations at the end of a sentence (which the original regular expression couldn't handle):

```
This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned.
application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013.
Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004.
Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph.
Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph about the U.S.
The check looks good.
```

*Note: to test this, I slightly modified your input text to have an abbreviation at the end of the sentence, I added: `Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph about the U.S. The check looks good.`*

If regular expression isn't a requirement for you, I would encourage you to test it out, since covering all the edge-cases with regular expressions can be cumbersome.

---

**Original regex approach**

One approach could be to better define/simplify what the "end of a sentence" is, to avoid needing to define all special cases. In your example, this seems to be a reasonable simplification:

*The sentence ends only if - there is a dot followed by a whitespace followed by a word which begins with a capital character and is at least 4 characters long.*

Using this simplification, you can use a lookahead assertion to match all  occurrences of "the end of a sentence" `\.\s(?=[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,})` and use this expression to split the text you provided using the `re.split` like so:

```
import re

text = "<your text>"

sentences = re.split(r"\.\s(?=[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,})", text)

print(sentences)
```

Given your data, these are the sentences obtained with this approach:

```
This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013
Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004
Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph
Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i wouldn't be knowing the end of sentence and sentence may start with one or two word. is there a way to do it using non-capturing group like what i have done by updating something?

Comment: Well, for a reg. expression to work, you need to be able to define some pattern.  If you cannot reasonably well define what the sentence looks like, what the end of it looks like, or what the non-sentence-ending exceptions are (as suggested by @dinhit), it is difficult to solve it with just regular expression(s).

You can try libraries such as [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize.html), [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd), [gensim](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/docs/gensim.summarization.textcleaner.split_sentences) to do the tokenization.

Comment: I adjusted my original response to use a stanza library, I think it gives the best results - please check it out and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how specific you want the places to be where you want to split, you might for example use an alternation with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Then in the callback check for the existence of the capture group in the pattern. If the capture group is there, then use it in the replacement followed by 2 newlines (or what you want to place after it)

In the other case, there is just the match `x.group()` and that should stay there so you would put that in the replacement.

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z](?:[a-z]+\.(?:\s+\d+\.)?|(?:\.[A-Z]+)*\.?)(?!\S)|([!.?])\s(?=[A-Z])
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `[A-Z]` Match a char A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `[a-z]+\.` Match 1+ chars a-z and a `.`
  - `(?:\s+\d+\.)?` Optionally match 1+ whitespace chars, 1+ digits and `.`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:\.[A-Z]+)*\.?` Match optional repetitions of `.` followed by A-Z and an optional dot
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `|` Or
- `([!.?])\s` Capture **group 1**, capture one of `!` `.` `?` and match a whitespace char
- `(?=[A-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char A-Z directly to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/viU7wx/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w8woKV)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)[A-Z](?:[a-z]+\.(?:\s+\d+\.)?|(?:\.[A-Z]+)*\.?)(?!\S)|([!.?])\s(?=[A-Z])"
s = "This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013. Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004. Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph. Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph."

result = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1) + "\n\n" if x.group(1) else x.group(), s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
This Application is a Continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 15/731,069, filed on Apr. 14, 2017, which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/998,574, filed on Jan. 21, 2016 which was a Continuation of U.S. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 (now U.S. Pat. No. 9,286,457) filed on Mar. 6, 2014, which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/931,340, filed on Jan. 31, 2011, (now U.S. Pat. No. 8,842,887) which was a Continuation in Part of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/627,413 filed on Nov. 30, 2009, (now U.S. Pat. No. 7,916,907) which was a continuation of application Ser. No. 11/151,412, filed on Jun. 14, 2005, now abandoned. application Ser. No. 14/198,695 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/851,884, filed on Mar. 15, 2013.

Application Ser. No. 12/931,340 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 61/456,901, filed on Nov. 15, 2010 and application Ser. No. 11/151,412 claims the benefit of Provisional Application No. 60/579,422 filed on Jun. 14, 2004.

Testing some more example of U.S.A and U.S in my paragraph.

Checking Fig. 3. in my paragraph.
```